# How to show the NavigationMenu after you hide it in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, menu, navigation

I need to make some of the NavigationMenu items visible only to some users.
In my case I need to make 2 of them available only to admin.

I searched google and I found a command which works :

NavigationMenu.Items.Remove(NavigationMenu.FindItem("HERE GOES THE NAME OF THE MENU I NEED TO REMOVE"));

Till here,everything is ok.
But which command do I need to use to make it available again ?

Please help me. Thnx in advance ;)

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationMenu.Items.Remove(NavigationMenu.FindItem("Employers"));

        if (Matrix.UserLoggedId == Guid.Empty)
        {

            hlLogin.Visible = true;
            lblUsername.Visible = false;
            lnkLogout.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // here goes the code to add the menu
            hlLogin.Visible = false;
            lblUsername.Visible = true;
            lnkLogout.Visible = true;

            Marin.Employee.DetailsDataTable emp = Matrix.GetEmployeeByUniqueId(Matrix.UserLoggedId);
            if (emp.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                lblUsername.Text = emp.Rows[0]["Firstname"].ToString();


                bool isAdmin =Convert.ToBoolean(emp.Rows[0]["isAdmin"]);
                if (isAdmin)
                {
                    //here goes the code to show the menu
                }
                else
                {

                   NavigationMenu.Items.Remove(NavigationMenu.FindItem("Employers"));
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replace x with correct values.

```
var mi = new MenuItem(x,x,x,x)
NavigationMenu.Items.Add(mi);
```

For more info on MenuItem check this -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.aspx

Comment: It seems that this is the solution,because it shows and hides the menu,but when I sign in as admin and click the menu it doesn't make any action. Do you mind if I post here the code and take a look at it where my mistake might be ? THANKSSSS ;)

Comment: did you use `new Manuitem("label here","","","url here");`

Comment: No,I didn't use it,didn't use any url .

Comment: Yesssssssssss,I did it....thank you so much ! I added the url of the page my navigation menu has to redirect me and it worked fine :) Thank you so much @rs